# Integer trims starting zeros

Tags: c#, integer

Simply,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string [ ] args )
    {
        int i = 010;

        Console.WriteLine( i );

        Console.ReadKey( );
    }
}
```

Output:

> 10

**How** to stop trimming leading zeros ?
Decimals have same output, strings aren't best solution too.

Comment: You're confusing the data with representation. The value (the data) is `10`, not `010` and not `00000000010`. But representation can be any, depending on how you format it. And it will be a string.

Comment: I'm sure that you are aware that 010 isn't a number, 10 is, therefore 010 doesn't have any value except as a mere series of digits.

Comment: Then how to format it to show the original value, they're barcode values on a database, then strings aren't the best optimized solution here for comparisons !

Comment: So how are they stored in a database?

Comment: Just because your data is purely numeric doesn't mean it shouldn't be stored as a string.  For example, phone numbers should be stored as strings.  They may take a few more cycles to compare, but unless you've profiled and discovered that performance is unacceptable you shouldn't worry.  You'll only make things more difficult for yourself.

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim - Barcodes aren't numbers (although they consist of numbers). What comparisons are you talking about?

Comment: If you're worried about comparing values you should identify each row with a unique row key that is not the natural key defined by the barcode value itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store it in a string. Then you can cast it back to integer when you need calculations, then cast it back to string when you're done using the desired format.

Comment: I'm using it on a MSSQL database, strings aren't the best optimized solution!

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim - Integers and other numeric types don't store trailing zeros. Period. Not in C#, not in MSSQL. Trailing zeros are an artifact of representation as a string. So your implementation will *always* consist of a string somewhere. The details of that implementation depend on your scenario.

Comment: @SystemDown I think you mean "leading zeros".

Comment: @phoog - Right! I keep confusing those two.

Comment: @SystemDown it's especially easy to confuse them given that both trailing and leading zeros can be ignored, depending on which side of the decimal separator we're talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Number types only keep track of the binary representation of the number, not the string representation you use to initialize them.

You can format it when you output it if you want a constant number of digits:

```
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("D8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:D8}", i);
```

Will print "i" containing at least 8 digits.  Any missing digits will become leading zeroes.